# Windows 7 system files are not found

Tags: windows-7

My brand new Lenovo laptop is a complete mess because of my two years old sister :(

I don't know what she did exactly , I left here for half an hour and when I came back I found that all applications have the Real Player icon , I thought that uninstalling it would resolve the problem but I was absolutely wrong !!

Now , all applications are not accessible... Microsoft 2010 package has an unknown application icon , and system features are not found such as adjusting date/time .

I tried to recover the system from safe mode by using system restore , but that feature was inaccessible too.

It's a complete disaster ... How can I recover my windows 7 without ought to reinstall it all over again ?!

I swear to God if killing her would bring things the way they were I wouldn't hesitate for a second -_-

Please help :(

Comment: Based on the information you provided, it is clear that killing your sister will not help restore your laptop.  If you want additional advice, you will need to provide a lot more information.  Describe what is working and what is not working.  What have you tried so far?  Did Tyson's answer solve you problem?  If not what happened?

Comment: Not sure what to think about leaving a laptop turned on and not locked (Windows key + L) at a place where a 2 year old can access it.....well actually I do.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a brand new laptop it likely has a recovery partition.  I found [this](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht036037) recent Lenovo support document that should help you re-install windows from the recovery partition.

Comment: thanks for the pretty informative article link you provided , I did tried what it suggested but none of the approaches restored my laptop as it was . I think I will burn it :3 Thanks anyways :)